# Input: n, Output: all +ve numbers up-to n with 4 divisors?

Tags: java

when given an integer n, prints out all positive numbers up to n with 4 positive divisors.

*Examples:*

```
10 --> 6 8 10  
16 --> 6 8 10 14 15
```

### My code

```
public class ass5_q1 {  

public static int divide(int n) 
{
     int x;
     int v = 0;
    for ( x = 1; x <= n; x++ )    
     {
        if ( n % x == 0 )         
        {  
           v++;
        }
     }
     if(v==4)
         System.out.println(v);
     return v;

}
     public static void main(String[] args)

{
     Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
     int m;
     m = read.nextInt();
     for(int i=0; i<=m; i++)
     {
         if(i==divide(m))
         {
             System.out.print(i);
         }

     }
   System.out.println();
 }
}
```

but I can't find correct code ..
what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THİS İS THE CORRECT CODE

package neew;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class newa

{
    public static int divide(int n) 
    {
         int x;
         int v = 0;
        for ( x = 1; x <= n; x++ )
         {
            if ( n % x == 0 )
            {
               v++;
            }
         }
        if(v==4) 
        {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
        return n;
    }

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    int z;
    int x;
    x = read.nextInt();
    for(int r = 1; r<=x; r++)
    {
        z = divide(r);

    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(v==4)
     System.out.println(v);
 return v;
```

You're returning `v` in any case, you should `return v;` only if `v == 4`, so you should place it under the `if` statement:

```
 if(v==4) {
     System.out.println(v);
     return v;
 }
 //Here you should return something that indicates otherwise,
 //think about a special value that has no meaning if v == 4 not satisfied
```

<sup>That's why we should have `{` and `}` even for one line statements, it prevents bugs like this one</sup>